# Is it possible to do CRC check for a .CSV file using windows forms C#

Tags: c#, csv, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I am building a GUI using C#(Windows Form). Basically, my GUI generates one file(.CSV format).

For example, assume that my GUI generated the following .csv file.

`Username, Password, MachineID
abc, abc, 123
jkl, jkl, 789
rst, rst, 456`

Now I will be implementing a feature where my GUI should read back the above-generated file and while reading back I want to validate the file because before reading that .csv file and displaying its contents into my GUI, I want to validate whether user changed the file content manually or not.

Henceforth I am just checking whether is there any **CRC check method** to validate the file? or please suggest me any other method to validate/to find if the user modified the file manually or not?

Comment: How are you going to hold references to the file you have created? The answer below shows one method of creating a form of checksum - but you need to know what the correct value should be when you read the file back.

Comment: @PaulF is correct.  You'd need to store the checksum either in a separate file or as part of the CSV file if you can't store it in memory.

Comment: There isn't much point in demanding a CRC check, it is much simpler and more bullet-proof to just calculate the hash.  Readily available in .NET from SHA1Managed and friends.

Comment: The filename is fixed that would be my reference. I need to understand the below code completely I don't know whether it works or not, if it works then for instance if am able to create a checksum before generating the file then I will add the checksum into the end of file only and while reading back the file again I will recalculate the checksum of the file and I will compare with the previously stored checksum. Am I right?

Comment: How do I compute a HASH value for a string? All my data which needed to be stored into a CSV file is available into a string before storing. Now how do I compute a HASH value for this string? only after calculating the HASH value I can store its value to the end of the file. Please help

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed(v=vs.110).aspx there is sample code there

Comment: The above example accepts only bytes. But I have all the contents in a string(comma separated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this class

[crc32 class](https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs)

and then use it like that

```
   DamienG.Security.Cryptography.Crc32 crc32 = new DamienG.Security.Cryptography.Crc32();
            String CSVCrc32hash = String.Empty;


            foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(**here your csv file bytes in byte[] format**))
            {

                CSVCrc32hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
            }

//the CSVCrc32hash is the hash
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this. Do I need to incorporate the above code while generating CSV file or while reading back the generated CSV?

Comment: you need to use this in both ways, for example.. after you generate the file and  before you store it in the DB or sent it to the client you will create the crc32 hash and store it somewhere (DB,CSV file etc) along with the file name. So  when you want to validate a file you will generate the hash and compare the hash with the hash for the file name that you  stored when you created  the file.

Comment: Example--> I just generated a csv file with the name report_05_10_2017.csv ,before i store the file somewhere or give it to the client i will pass the file through the method above and get the CSVCrc32hash  ... Then I can create a table in the DB like    ID,FileName,CRC32Hash   and store there the file names along with their hashes..  when  you want to validate a file with the name report_05_10_2017.csv  you will create again a hash for the file and compare it with the hash in the DB if they are identical they will have the same hash